# Some GSM AT commands don't return anything

Tags: gsm, at-command, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to build a GPS tracker where a Raspberry Pi Pico sends data to a Firebase server through a GSM module, using MicroPython. To test the GSM SIM800C modem I sent AT commands to get network operator, then called a phone which works, but when I try to use SABPR to connect to GPRS it stops responding. No "OK" or "ERROR". Response from the REPL in Thonny:

```
>>> GSM_uart.write('AT\n')
3
>>> GSM_uart.readline()
b'AT\r\n'
>>> GSM_uart.readline()
b'OK\r\n'
>>> GSM_uart.write('AT+COPS?\n')
9
>>> GSM_uart.readline()
b'AT+COPS?\r\n'
>>> GSM_uart.readline()
b'+COPS: 0,0,"AirTel"\r\n'
>>> GSM_uart.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"\n')
30
>>> GSM_uart.readline()
b'AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"\r\n'
>>> GSM_uart.readline()

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   KeyboardInterrupt:
```

I have to send a KeyboardInterrupt to do anything. Keeping it that way for a few minutes doesn't change anything. Ignoring `readline` doesn't achieve anything either. I think Python misinterprets later commands because they have dual inverted commas, because the ones that work don't have that. If so, how do I get around that?

Comment: By "dual inverted commas" you mean "double quotes"? No, Python doesn't do anything weird with them; when they're enclosed in single quotes they're just data and passed through unmodified, same as any other data.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy idk then, thing is if I enclosed this in single quotes it would give a syntax error, which is why I thought this way. Regardless, something is causing stuff to get unresponsive and I'd like to solve why

Comment: To me, offhand, this smells more like a problem with the specific AT commands being run (in the context of the device they're being run on) than anything else. Unfortunately, that's not a class of problem we're well equipped to help with here -- remember that questions can require a [mre] to be on topic, and if the issue can't be reproduced without having specific hardware...

Comment: Your problem very well might be Thonny. Thonny is a very unstable editor that breaks all the time for all kinds of weird reasons. Learn how to use RShell to get scripts on your board and start a REPL. Then run your script that way and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Does it change if you send `GSM_uart.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"\r')` (please note the trailing `'\r'`). Please also note that PDP context activation can actually take up to 3 minutes to succeed (or to result in an error). Could you check if your device is registered to  GPRS network by issuing `AT+CGREG?`   ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wouldn't know, I am looking into bypassing the microcontroller and connecting directly to the GSM modem for now. @MichaelGuidry I tried using rshell, it has the same problem, so I don't think thonny is the culprit @RobertoCaboni I tried the trailing `\r` but it didn't make much difference, just spat out two `\r` 's in the ECHO response. Also `AT+CGREG` returns `0,5` ; so it is registered. Do you think that the problem is it being SIM800C ? It shouldn't be but everyone else in the guides has SIM800L , is there a difference except the size?

Comment: @Psynapse_261 I don't think so. In that case you should get an error . How long do you wait for a response? PS: another attempt: `GSM_uart.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"\r')` (CONTYPE in capital letters).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I have tried waiting for a couple seconds to minutes, no error. I'll try the command you sent me.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni `GSM_uart.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"\r')` gave the same result - no errors, nothing, just blank until I send a keyboard interrupt. I'm trying to get my hands on a SIM800L to see if it is the same on that board